# Absolutely convergent series greater than or equal to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be a complex number such that $\Re(z)>\dfrac{1}{2}$ and let $d \in \mathbb{N}$ be a integer such that $d \geq 0$

Is it true that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\left|
\dfrac
{ln(n+1)^d}
{(n+1)^z}
-
\dfrac
{ln(n)^d}
{n^z}
\right|
\geq
1
$$

Thanks

Comment: For $d = 0$, yes. For $d > 0$, the sum is less than $1$ if $\operatorname{Re} z$ is large enough.

Comment: thanks @DanielFischer, can you tell me if is it true for $1/2<Re z< 1$

Comment: For large enough $d$ ($d\geqslant 2$ suffices), it will then hold. (If there is an $n$ with $(\log n)^d \geqslant \frac{1}{2} n^{\operatorname{Re} z}$, then the sequence $\frac{(\log n)^d}{n^z}$ starts from $0$, passes through a point with modulus $\geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ and then goes back to $0$, so that the length of the path through these points surely is at least $1$.) For $d = 1$, it will only hold for some such $z$. If $z = 1-\varepsilon$ with small positive $\varepsilon$, the sum will be $2\frac{\log 3}{3^{1-\varepsilon}} < 1$.